# nuxt 3 A composable that requires access to the Nuxt instance was called outside of a plugin, Nuxt hook, Nuxt middleware, or Vue setup function

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js, vuejs3

I want to make asynchronous composables with useFetch(), $fetch and asyncDataFetch() but there is a constant error, which says:

```
Error: [nuxt] A composable that requires access to the Nuxt instance was called outside of a plugin, Nuxt hook, Nuxt middleware, or Vue setup function
```

I want to use nuxt instances outside setup...

But I don't know how to do that, I heard about useNuxtApp() but I didn't quite understand...

Comment: Can you share the code on the composables you want to create?